# Subindexing and Marginal Differencing in Power Query (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

I have this dataset:

```
User    Date    Time
A   9/1/2019    8:00 AM
A   9/1/2019    10:00 AM
A   9/1/2019    4:00 PM
A   9/1/2019    5:00 PM
A   9/2/2019    8:00 AM
A   9/2/2019    5:00 PM
B   9/1/2019    9:00 AM
B   9/1/2019    3:00 PM
B   9/1/2019    5:00 PM
```

The first thing I want to do is add a subindex on User and Date.

```
User    Date    Time    User/Date Index
A   9/1/2019    8:00 AM     1
A   9/1/2019    10:00 AM    2
A   9/1/2019    4:00 PM     3
A   9/1/2019    5:00 PM     4
A   9/2/2019    8:00 AM     1
A   9/2/2019    5:00 PM     2
B   9/1/2019    9:00 AM     1
B   9/1/2019    3:00 PM     2
B   9/1/2019    5:00 PM     3
```

The second thing I want is a column that takes the difference between times in its row (A) and the row after it (A+1). "n/a" means I don't really care about this value. I just want the interday marginal differences.

```
User    Date    Time    User/Date Index Marginal Difference
A   9/1/2019    8:00 AM     1           02:00:00
A   9/1/2019    10:00 AM    2           06:00:00
A   9/1/2019    4:00 PM     3           01:00:00
A   9/1/2019    5:00 PM     4              n/a
A   9/2/2019    8:00 AM     1           09:00:00
A   9/2/2019    5:00 PM     2              n/a
B   9/1/2019    9:00 AM     1           06:00:00
B   9/1/2019    3:00 PM     2           02:00:00
B   9/1/2019    5:00 PM     3              n/a
```

How can I achieve this in Excel's power query?

Answer (score 0):

These requirements are both a bit complex.

First I recommend you review my demo file "Power Query demo - Running total and Running Count". Its an Excel files you can download from my OneDrive demo folder:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AGLFDsG7h6JPgw4

You can ignore the Running Total, but the Running Count is equivalent to your subindex requirement.

For referring to the next row, first add a Index column (using the Add Column ribbon), then you can use this syntax in a calculated column:

```
= #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[My Column]
```

That means: refer to the table of data "as at" the step "Added Index", find the row numbered one higher than the current row, and return the value of [My Column].